# What is "uns" in C?

Tags: c, debugging, typedef, unsigned

I came across this C library: http://www.ucw.cz/libucw/
It contains a sorting routine: http://www.ucw.cz/libucw/doc/sort.html
In array_simple.h there this function declaration:

```
static void ASORT_PREFIX(sort)(ASORT_ARRAY_ARG uns array_size ASORT_EXTRA_ARGS)
```

and further in the code:

```
struct stk { int l, r; } stack[8*sizeof(uns)];
uns sp = 0;
```

There is no more #includes in that file and no mention about "uns".
Needless to say neither VC2010 nor GCC (mingw32) understand what uns is. Help !

Comment: looks like a `#def`ed user defined data type !

Comment: If you can't find it in headers or the source file, look in the Makefile(s) for a compiler switch like `-Duns=unsigned`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
typedef unsigned int uns;
```

http://www.ucw.cz/libucw/doc/def_index.html

It is in ucw/config.h, which is automatically included by ucw/lib.h.

(I wonder why they didn't choose `uint` for an alias instead. Although, some systems already have it as this exact type definition.)

Comment: I thought I just need to include that one file; I found some code using this same alias in google but no explanation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://www.ucw.cz/libucw/doc/basics.html#type_uns) says that it is a `typedef` for `unsigned int`:

> `typedef unsigned int uns;`
>
> A better pronounceable alias for `unsigned int`.

Comment: "uns" is better pronounceable? They must be talking about some other language than English (vielleicht Deutsch?).